# Set cookies as secure in Chrome devtools?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

In Devtools -> Application -> Cookies, you can create and modify cookies. However, I can't set `secure`, `httponly`, or `samesite`. How can I update a cookie to secure through the UI? I'm using Chrome 79 on Win10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot currently do this. I have raised a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1040096) to enable it.

**Update**: This has been added to DevTools and is available as of Chrome 81.
[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing cookie editing functionality]