# Modify SameSite and Secure properties of a cookie in Chrome for Android

Tags: cookies, samesite

In Chrome, it's possible to modify a cookie by clicking `F12 > Application > Select cookie > Double click a property` and edit it. However, this doesn't work for `Secure` and `SameSite`. Does anyone know how to do this? Even better, is it possible to do this on an Android phone? I want to set the `SameSite=None` and `Secure=true`.

**EDIT:**
Apparantly in Chrome 81 (Beta as of now) it works for editing SameSite/Secure properties on Chrome Desktop. However, when I try to remotely edit a cookie when browsing a website on my Android phone, this still doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do this?

**Repro steps:**

1. Go to URL: `chrome://inspect/#devices` in Chrome 81
2. Connect your phone and try to remotely browser a website on your Android phone
3. Go go `Application > Cookies > Double click SameSite field` - still doesn't work

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookies as secure in Chrome devtools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439648/set-cookies-as-secure-in-chrome-devtools)

Comment: No unfortunately, it doesn't work when trying to remotely edit the cookie on my Android.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [59648007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439648/set-cookies-as-secure-in-chrome-devtools/59648007). This has been added to DevTools and is available as of Chrome 81.
[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing cookie editing functionality]

Comment: I can confirm that this work for editing the ```SameSite``` property of a cookie when browsing with Windows 10. However, it doesn't work to edit the property of a cookie when the remote target is my Android phone. Go to URL: ```chrome://inspect/#devices```, connect your phone and try to remotely browser your Android phone and then go ```Application > Cookies > Double click SameSite field``` - it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Chrome running on the device is version 81 or above? If I use desktop Chrome 81+ to connect to Android Chrome 81+, I can edit the cookies. If I use desktop Chrome 81+ to connect to Android Chrome **80** then I cannot edit.